# Django convert a parent class/model into a child class/model

Tags: django, inheritance, parent-child

Is there any way to convert a parent object to one of its child objects such that the object retains the same old information (including the old key). I have implemented concrete inheritance. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered making the base class abstract, and inheriting from it ?

Comment: That is not an option for me. I need objects of both parent and child type.

Comment: what are you going to do about fields on the child model, which the parent instance will have no values for?

Comment: I want to convert the parent instance into a child instance, and for new fields, I will set these variables during/after conversion. My question is: How do I do the conversion?

Comment: cannot You just pass this instance of parent to childs __init__ ?